# Is PCR test required for a child travelling to Spain?

Tags: air-travel, covid-19, spain

It is quite unclear what the testing requirements are for children under 12 years old when travelling to Spain, for non-EU citizens or residents.

Is there some information available that clarifies it?

Travelling from the USA if more specificity is required.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Spain Travel Health](https://www.spth.gob.es) official website:

> **What do I have to bring with me to pass the sanitary control at the airport?**
>
> - has been vaccinated against COVID-19, with full vaccination schedule, at least 14 days prior to arrival in Spain.
> - a diagnostic test (sample collection) has been performed within 72 hours prior to arrival in Spain for NAAT (nucleic acid amplification tests, e.g. RT-PCR, RT-LAMP, TMA) / 48 hours for RAT (rapid antigen test), the result of which has been negative.
> - has recovered from COVID-19, after the disease has passed, provided that more than 11 days have elapsed since the first positive NAAT test was performed, and shall be valid for up to 180 days thereafter.

and then:

> Children under 12 years of age are not required to present these certificates or supporting documents.

So to answer your question, kids under 12 are not required to have a PCR test.

Comment: Bear in mind, you will need any one of those documents, not all three.